# Twitter API access using Python (newbie:Help Needed)

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

How can i get twitter information (number of followers, following, etc.) about a set of twitter handles using the Twitter API?
i have already used Python-Twitter library but this only gives me information about my own twitter account, but i need the same for other twitter users (i have a list).
Can you please guide me in the right direction? or refer to some good blogs/articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the latest tweets from specific users, Twitter offers the Streaming API.

The Streaming API is the real-time sample of the Twitter Firehose. This API is for those developers with data intensive needs. If you're looking to build a data mining product or are interested in analytics research, the Streaming API is most suited for such things.

If you're trying to access old information, the REST API with its severe request limits is the only way to go.